# Error R8: Missing class: sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor Occurring during Release, APP crashes

Tags: android, proguard, vpn

I am creating a VPN app, When I build apk in debug app works fine but in release mode apk generated with warning `Missing class: sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor`.

App get crashed after opening it. disabling proguard is also not working. 
I have added proguard-rules.pro file but not added any code in that.

can you find the reason of error

Comment: Without code, no

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 does not have class `sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor` anymore:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8192780

If it's Java 8, you could try to keep the class:

```
-keep class sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor { *; }
-keep class sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService { *; }
```

Comment: I tried this method by keeping above class there is same error